# Link two points smoothly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to link two points smoothly. I tried to do it with the following code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0.7,0) -- (0.7,6);
        \draw (0,6) -- (0,-0.8);
        \draw (0.5,-1.2) -- (2.2,-1.2);
        \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,-0.8) (0.5,-1.2)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

but I got linear link, instead of smooth link.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option `rounded corners` can help, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[rounded corners=10pt] (0, 1) -- (0, -1.2) -- (1.2, -1.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

The smoothest curve joining two points is straight.

You want a Bézier curve:

```
\documentclass[border=4,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,1) -- (0,-0.8) .. controls (0,-1.2) .. (0.5,-1.2) -- (1.2,-1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]